# Create permalink page for article using JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a page that grabs a list of articles from a JavaScript file and then lists them and they can be expanded on that page; however, I need them to be linked to.

Essentially, I want to be able to give a permalink for all my articles individually. My idea was to create a blank document and then send which article (via an article id number?) to that page to allow it to be grabbed that way; however, I don't know how to go about sending that information using JavaScript or if that's even possible. Something along the lines of `www.myurl.com/article/d9f8ve` would show me the `article.html` dummy page that would generate the article with the id `d9f8ve` from a JSON file or similar.

Here is the [CodePen](http://codepen.io/jacob_johnson/pen/qbjRvR).

I don't need someone to do it for me; just any kind of help would be awesome. I'm just confused about how I'd dynamically create this page or send information to a newly created page. Is it possible to create a page constructor that send information as I create a page like I would when creating a class in C# or Java? Something like `new Page("d9f8ve")` and then the page would be created with that string var carried within the JavaScript file?

I tried:

```
var opened = window.open("");
opened.document.write("<html><head><title>My title</title></head><body>test</body></html>");
```

The problem with this is that it doesn't provide me with a permalink or *actually* create a page so I don't actually have any way to come back to this page at any time.

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: You can perfectly make all you need, but you need first to try by yourself and then ask us the problems that you have while you are developing. You can make objects to instance like `new Page(param)` but I think that you can try first with a framework or library like **Backbone.js** (http://backbonejs.org/) that makes all for you.

Comment: As a clue: you can read the `window.location` and strip the key that identify your page. Then pass it to your function and switch the keys to show the content you need every time

Comment: Ok, ok. So I kind of understand what you mean but I'm still confused. using `window.location.href` delivers me the current url which I can strip to the last bit (the article id i.e. `www.myurl.com/article/12345`); however, how do I get that link to work? Like, typing that url in will just give me a `page not found` error. I'm looking into Backbone now (so forgive me if the answer is seemingly obvious from that regard) but I was wondering if that is the idea.

Comment: You need or a server-side friendly URL (search about it, you can make it with PHP and .htaccess so simplest), or otherwise with backbone you can make it with a hash (example `www.yoururl.com/#/article/12345`, so the hash will be `/article/12345` but is not an independent page, is the index.html.